# Definition of class and variable with the same name

Tags: c++

There is this code:

```
int x;

//void x(); // error: redefinition of 'x' as different kind of symbol

class x {}; // works ok

int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

Why is it legal to define variable and class with the same name but it is not legal to define variable and function with the same name?

Comment: What do you propose `&x` does for the function-variable pair?

Comment: @chris, you could equally have asked what should sizeof(x) do for the class-variable pair?   (Apologies for necro)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's going on here is specific to C++. The use of `x` as a class name is hidden.

Section 3.3.7 (Name Hiding) paragraph 2:

> A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name of an object, function, or enumerator declared in the same scope. If a class or enumeration name and an object, function, or enumerator are declared in the same scope (in any order) with the same name, the class or enumeration name is hidden wherever the object, function, or enumerator name is visible.

Answer (score 14):

**First Case:** 2 Identifiers

```
int x;
void x();
```

**Second Case:** 1 Identifier, 1 Typename

```
int x;
class x {};
```

The compiler can't handle the first case because you have 2 identifiers with the same name, so there could be an ambiguity. (Example: Try getting the memory address of one of them. That's one case where an ambiguity could arise)

The compiler can handle the second case because one is a type and the other is an identifier, and because it knows where to expect a type and where to expect an identifier, there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

This is needed for backward-compatibility with C (if I recall, some UNIX headers define both a struct and a variable with the same name).

You can disambiguate between a class and a variable/function:

```
int x;

class x {};

int main()
{
    x = 42; // global int x

    //x obj; // error
    class x obj; // use class-tag to disambiguate
}
```

But you cannot disambiguate between a variable and a function.

See also the book *"The Design and Evolution of C++"* by Bjarne Stroustrup, §2.8.2.

Answer (score 2):

`union`, `enum` and `struct` (and I suppose `class` too) together have seperate "name buckets" (has nothing to do with C++ namespaces!) from ordinary identifiers. This becomes clear in C, because you have to prefix the names with `struct` etc.

I don't have it for C++, but this is from the C standard:

```
6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers

If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at
any point in a translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses
that refer to different entities.

 Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers,
as follows:
— label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);

— the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by 
 following any32) of the keywords struct, union, or enum);

— the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a 
separate name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the 
expression used to access themember via the . or -> operator);

— all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary 
  declarators or as enumeration constants).
```

Comment: This is completely wrong.  The only "namespaces" in C++ are those defiend using the keyword `namespace` (or the global namespace).  This is one case where C and C++ are quite different.

Comment: This should not be the selected answer. This is 100% wrong for C++, and this question is tagged C++ only.

Comment: @JamesKanze DavidHammen I know, "namespaces" is the wrong word, but what should I call it instead? Please back up your statement that these rules of disambiguation are complety wrong for C++.

Comment: @typ1232 David Hammen has already quoted the most important
part. §3.3.10/2 is also relevant: "A class name or enumeration
name can be hidden by the name of a variable, data member,
function, or enumerator declared in the same scope."  Unless the
name is hidden, there is no need to the elaborated type
specifier.  This is one of the basics of C++; you don't need to
write `class MyType`; just `MyType` suffices.

Comment: And your edit doesn't correct it.  There are no separate "name buckets" or anything like it.  _If_ the compiler finds the name twice in the same scope, it chooses the one which is not a class definition unless it is in an extended type specifier.  (This doesn't normally happen, however, in well written C++ code.  This special rule is just to allow us to include things like `<sys/stat.h>`, which were originally written in C.)

Comment: typedef, class, struct, union and enum cannot have same  type name. member variable of a struct/class cannot have same name as a class. Please do the world a favor and take your "answer" down. C++ is not C, and we already have enough incompetent programmers, there's no need for more of them. Compile [this](http://pastebin.com/hqgcSxNX), see what happens.

Comment: @SigTerm That's not what I meant. All class,struct,union etc _together_ have a same "name bucket" for disambiguation. It may sound like that though, will try to clarify that.

Comment: @typ1232 In C++, all class, struct, union, typedef, variable, function, reference and template have the same "name bucket".  The only thing which is separate is preprocessor symbols.  C++ is _not_ C in this respect, and follows completely different name lookup rules.  In particular, it allows multiple definitions of the same symbol in the same scope (with restrictions).