# Where the same type name and identifier name be suggested to use?

Tags: c++

In question [Use of typename keyword with typedef and new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421306/use-of-typename-keyword-with-typedef-and-new).

These codes be introduced:

```
struct A 
{
    struct X { string name; };
    static const int X = 100;
};
```

I usually use different names to make a disambiguation. I want to know if there is a circumstance one can benefit from the usage of the same name.

Comment: Other than obfuscation, I can't think of one. Upvoted for intrigue.

Comment: I find my question maybe duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592988/definition-of-class-and-variable-with-the-same-name). An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16593281/7314875)  seems to be the answer.

Comment: Because it is smurf as `smurf smurf; smurf(smurf);` ;-)

Comment: Some code naming conventions enforce different naming rules for different kinds of things so such a confusion won't ever occur.

Comment: @Kyno that answer fails to name at least one such header for compatibility with C. So, if it's true, it sure needs enhancement.